# While loop only iterates twice through an array with 4 elements

Tags: c#, file, logic

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
        String contents = "LINE";

        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contents)) 
        {
            contents = sr.ReadLine();

            foreach (TSPlayer plr in newPlayers.Keys) 
            {
                if (plr.Name.ToLower() == contents.ToLower() || plr.UserAccountName.ToLower() == contents.ToLower())
                {
                    TShock.Utils.ForceKick(plr, "Bad name. GO AWAY!");
                    newPlayers.Remove(plr);
                }
            }
        }

        sr.Close();
```

I am reading from a text file with 4 lines all containing values (no blank lines). The while loop above only reads the first 2 values from the file and then stops.

I have tried using a regular For loop and a Foreach loop after splitting the contents of the file at '\n', but the same thing happened.

I have no idea why this is happening. I know for sure that the array has 4 elements because I manually displayed the value at the index (eg. contents[2]). So it is read from the file correctly.

It's just whenever I try and access the third value it stops.

Thanks for the help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: You likely have an empty line, or a line which consists of spaces or tabs only in your file. Try: `var lines = File.ReadLines(path).Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).ToArray();` and check how many lines you got.

Answer (score 4):

MSDN says that

> Return Value
>   Type: System.String
>   The next line from the input stream, or null if the end of the input stream is reached.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

What you have is

```
while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contents)) 
{
    contents = sr.ReadLine();
```

If the 3rd line of your file is just whitespace then your loop will exit, what it should be is probably just

```
while (contents != null)
```

Comment: I see what you mean. The text file doesn't contain any white space-lines but I've incorporated what you've suggested. It still doesn't work. :(

Comment: If it's not the whitespace, then I would run the program in the debugger (or use the linq below). If TShock.Utils.ForceKick does something like Environment.Exit() or throws an exception, that could also simply stop execution. Debug through the method and see which line it's stopping on.

Comment: I put a debug at the top of the while loop to test it. It didn't reach the debug on the third iteration. I don't think TShock.Utils.ForceKick() stops the code because the first and second iteration work perfectly well when testing. TShock.Utils.ForceKick() is obsolete though. It says 'TShockAPI.Utils.ForceKick(TShockAPI.TSPlayer, string)' is obsolete: 'This method is for signature compatibility for external code only'. I don't know what this means :/

Comment: Step into the loop body and figure out which line it stops on. The debugger should allow you to debug the second iteration should let you see which line in the loop body you stop on. I'm not sure what the TShock API is, but you should review the documentation to see what method replaced that. Obsolete APIs mean that you should stop using them as they are no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have a logic issue in the line `while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contents))`. I suspect you have whitespace.

You also have a logic issue in your code that it must run through one look when you have a `null` or whitespace before it will exit.

You're better off avoiding this kind of loop and write your code using LINQ.

Try this:

```
var lines = new HashSet<string>(
    File
        .ReadAllLines(path)
        .Select(line => line.Trim().ToLower())
        .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)));

var matches =
    from plr in newPlayers
    let name = plr.Key.Name.ToLower()
    let userAccountName = plr.Key.UserAccountName.ToLower()
    where lines.Contains(name) || lines.Contains(userAccountName)
    select plr.Key;

foreach (var plr in matches.ToArray())
{
    TShock.Utils.ForceKick(plr, "Bad name. GO AWAY!");
    newPlayers.Remove(plr);
}
```

Comment: I used your code but nothing changed. My snippet code is also in a timer that elapses every 2.5 seconds. Does that matter? Or is it irrelevant?

Comment: @Davinatoratoe - It should work fine. A timer is irrelevant. WHen you say nothing changed, do you mean it stopped after two lines also?

Comment: @Davinatoratoe - Then I think you need to post the contents of your file. My code should return all valid lines. Could you check how many elements are in the `lines` hash set in my code when you run it?